# C Structure formula

Tags: c

**Having problems with the output of this formula:**

```
typedef struct
{
    float t, Vx, Vy, Px, Py;
} datapoint; 

datapoint *data;
data = malloc(steps * sizeof(datapoint));

data[0].Vx = (20*cos(30));           //30 is changed to radians
data[0].Vy = (20*sin(30));
data[0].Px = 0;
data[0].Py = 0;

steps=100;
i=1;

do
{
    printf("Time: %.2f\t",i*q5);

    // X
    data[i].Vx = data[i-1].Vx ;//- CalculateDrag(data[i-1].Vx, q4);
    data[i].Px = ((data[i-1].Px) + ((data[i].Vx) * i));

    printf("X = %.2f\t",data[i].Px);

    // Y
    data[i].Vy= data[i-1].Vy - (9.81)*i; //- CalculateDrag(data[i-1].Vy,q4);
    data[i].Py= data[i-1].Py + (data[i].Vy * i);

    printf("Y = %.2f\t", data[i].Py);

    printf("\n");
    i++;
} while(((data[i].Py) >0) && (i<=steps));
```

**The output should look like this:**

```
Time 0.10s: X = 1.73m Y = 1.00m
Time 0.20s: X = 3.46m Y = 1.90m
Time 0.30s: X = 5.20m Y = 2.71m
....
....
Time 2.00s: X = 34.64m Y = 1.36m
Time 2.10s: X = 36.37m Y = 0.40m
Time 2.20s: X = 38.11m Y = -0.66m
Landed at X = 38.11 at time 2.20s
```

But instead it prints out other values. Tried what i can but think there is maybe faulty code with the formula.

Comment: What values are you getting? And explain what the formula is, it looks like one of Newton's motion formulas.

Comment: Spend some time on formatting the code correctly. It helps you and others, to read the code. If you don't know how, then read other people's source code, and see how they indent, comment and format.

Comment: @Skizz: yess its one of his formulas... but the 'X' values are much bigger than the ones i should get and the 'Y' values jumps to negative values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to incrementally update values but are using absolute time values:

```
data[i].Px = ((data[i-1].Px) + ((data[i].Vx) * i));
```

since you're using the previous step value to calculate the new value (LHS of `+`) but adding on the current speed multiplied by the total time so far (RHS of `+`).

You either need to use absolute values:

```
data[i].Px = ((data[0].Px) + ((data[i].Vx) * i));
```

or incremental values:

```
data[i].Px = ((data[0].Px) + ((data[i].Vx) * t)); // where t is the time step
```

This works OK with Px since there's no acceleration component. The Py component has an acceleration component so doing the incremental version will introduce an error, since speed is not constant throughout the time step interval. You are approximating a curve with a series of linear sections.

I guess you're trying to implement the following:

> s = ut + at<sup>2</sup>/2

and trying to find the point where s.y is zero (hitting the ground). Rather than using an array and incrementally calculate s, use the above equation like this:

```
t = 0;
u = initial vector; 
a = gravity;

do
{
  t += time step;
  s = u * t + a * t * t / 2;
} while (s.x >= 0);
```

You would also benefit from using a vector library (not `std::vector`, but a math vector), then you can write the equation just like in the code above and not calculate the x and y parts individually. It will also be easier to migrate to a 3D system.

Answer (score 2):

From the code you've posted:

```
datapoint *data;
 data[0].Vx = (20*cos(30));
```

You're using data uninitalised here. It could be pointing anywhere and this is undefined behaviour so anything could happen.

I *think* from reading your code you wanted to do something like:

```
data = malloc(sizeof(datapoint) * steps);
```

Comment: yes thank you if implemented that, but my problem is the formula calculating the values in the do part of the do-while.

Comment: I think this is just a copy/paste error when writing the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your `datapoint` variable is not initialized, it points *somewhere* in the data, which can be really dangerous. You should initialize it by allocating memory for your structs. I suggest you use the `malloc` or `calloc` function to do so. e.g:

```
datapoint *data = calloc(sizeof(datapoint), 20);
```

Now that you have allocated your array of structs, you should deallocate it in the end, after you are done reading/writing it:

```
free(data);
```

**EDIT:**
I don't even think you are needing dynamic memory, it would be sufficient if you declare your array as follows:

```
datapoint data[20];
```

You do **not** have to `free` it now. In fact it would be dangerous to do so.